# TOSCA : "Cannot read XML Payload" message displayed when selected property and add Business Parameters

Tags: json, xml, tosca

I have a WADL file with list of web services. First I open it by File option in Tricentis Tosca API Scan. Then input correct properties in payload with JSON and get JSON response successfully. After that I use it as API Test Case.

So in Tosca Commander, "**Cannot read XML Payload**" message displayed when highlighted the property and add Business Parameters (Insert).

May I know any reason the error prompted ? I tried Tosca Web Services tutorial, it was fine and able to add the parameters for JSON payload.

[Error Message and JSON Request Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf7MX.png)

Tosca Version : 10.0

Comment: If this is for a specific software package, you may want to post on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems you are using version 10.0, where only XML was supported in the API Engine (in API Scan it worked already). In order to have it working in Tosca, you must upgrade to at least version 10.1 (see https://documentation.tricentis.com/en/1010/content/release_notes/key_features.htm).

Comment: Yes, I am using version 10.0. Thanks rolko. Besides upgrading, any workaround also can do the web service testing for WADL ? Is it the Webservice Engine 3.0 can used like API Engine ?

Comment: Yes, you can export as WSE 3.0 and test the WADL service with 10.0.